# Can't tell where my variables went, "missing positional arguments"

Tags: python, math

I started learning python a few months back, so i don't know alot of terms still.

This program fetches co-ordinates from a text file and finds out which point is closest to the user input.
the co-ordinates are listed lat,lon,cityname

of course i'm suprised that it can't find the variables, but i'm even more suprised that it found one but not the others.

I would be greatful if someone could explain to me why it can't find them.

```
points=open_points.read()
text_length_unfilt=len(points)
text_lenth=text_length_unfilt/3
cit_point = points.split(",")

#importing all of the items from math now
from math import radians
from math import atan2
from math import cos
from math import sin
from math import sqrt


#this allows the user to imput two numbers, one for lat, one for lon.
lat1=float(input("What is the Latatude of your point in degrees? "))
lon1=float(input("That's great. Now in degrees, what is the Longitude? "))


#function to reduce clutter

def calc_dist(lat1,lon1,lat2,lon2):
    #this part converts the degrees into radians for the equation
    lon1 = radians(lon1)
    lat1 = radians(lat1)
    lon2 = radians(lon2)
    lat2 = radians(lat2)

    #here i'm just using the equation from the rubrik
    a = sin((lat1 - lat2) / 2) ** 2 + cos(lat1) * cos(lat2) * sin((lon1 - lon2) / 2) ** 2
    c = 2 * atan2(sqrt(a), sqrt(1 - a))
    distance = 3958.8 * c
    return(distance)
```

and this is the error i get.

```
cit_dist=calc_dist((lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2))
TypeError: calc_dist() missing 3 required positional arguments: 'lon1', 'lat2', and 'lon2'
```

Comment: @john-gordon @johngordon
Thanks for your help, i ran into a similar issue recently. 
I have two functions one takes inputs with the input function and returns 4 values, and the other takes 4 parameters and returns one value. When i nest them, all 4 values count as one parameter , and when i try to unpack them it fails because they are float values.
 ` lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2 = get_location()

    distance(lon1,lat1,lon2,lat2)`

If you know what can be done, i'd apreciate it since all the responces i've found online refer to something called "model" which i am not using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
cit_dist=calc_dist((lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2))
```

The error is because you are using double parentheses.  `(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2)` is treated as a single tuple.